# Automator sequence to bulk rename and resize images and create thumbnails

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to automate my current routine daily tasks using AppleScript and desperately need help figuring out how this can be accomplished. Currently, I use Mac’s Automator tool in the following sequence to get to my end result, but since I don’t know how to put these actions into one workflow I have to constantly add and remove the same actions every time I go through this process. Can anyone explain how I can further automate these tasks and, ideally, put them into one script that would run when I drop a folder with images into it? Here is the sequence of actions I do:

Step #1:  I start with a folder that contains 40-50 images in .PNG format. In order to optimize them for the web I use automator’s Change Image Format command (Automator uses Pixelmator app to perform that, which I purchased separately) and convert them into .JPG format

Step #2:  I filter out all *.PNG images by extension and then Move them to trash using the applicable Automator actions.

Step #3:  I rename all of the images according to the following naming convention “Image-CATEGORY-NUMBER.jpg” using Rename Finder Items Action with Make Sequential parameter turned on. For example, the file names in my Landscapes folder will be "Image-Landscapes-1001.jpg", "Image-Landscapes-1002.jpg”, “Image-Landscapes-1003.jpg” and so on in sequence. I do have many different categories of images and need to be able to enter category name and the beginning number in the sequence before that portion of the script starts running, because I always start with the number where I previously left off. For example, if during the previous update I ended on the number 1003 and the last file in the folder was named “Image-Landscapes-1003.jpg”, then during the next update I will start with name “Image-Landscapes-1004.jpg” and go further in the same sequential manner.

For the last 3 steps, I realize that this is just one way of doing it and there might be other means to accomplish the same result. My ultimate goal here is for each full size image to create a thumbnail of a particular size (120x214 pixels) with a particular name (the name of a full-size image with "-thumb” at the end). For example a full size file named “Image-Landscapes-1004.jpg” should have a 120x214 pixel sized thumbnail with a name "“Image-Landscapes-1004-thumb.jpg” when this task is completed.

Step #4: I create a duplicate of each image using “Duplicate Finder Items” action.

Step #5: I replace the text in the name of each file that contains word “ copy" (these files are all of the duplicates created in the previous step) from “ copy” to “-thumb”. Please note there is a space sign before “ copy”, it is important for me to replace that space sig when I change the name to contain “-thumb” instead.

Step #6: I filter out all of the files that contain “-thumb” in the name and use “Fit Images” action to resize them to size 120x214 pixels (Automator also uses Pixelmator app for this action)

Many thanks for your help!
Mina

Answer (score 0):

You might just run a command like this in Terminal:

`i=1004;for f in ~/Pictures/folder/*.png;do d=${f%/*};n="Image-${d##*/}-$((i++))";convert "$f" -quality 88 ~/Desktop/"$n.jpg";convert "$f" -filter lanczos2 -gravity center -resize 120x214^ -extent 120x214 -quality 92 ~/Desktop/"$n-thumb.jpg";done`

You can install `convert` with `brew install imagemagick` after installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

`${f%/*}` removes the shortest `/*` pattern from the end and `${d##*/}` removes the longest `*/` pattern from the start. `-filter lanczos2` makes images look sharper than the default resizing method. `-gravity center -resize 120x214^ -extent 120x214` resizes and crops images so that their size is 120x214 pixels.